# What does "von etwas beunruhigt" mean?

Tags: phrase

> Als Grund gab die dreifache Mutter an, dass Mia manchmal so abweisend und beunruhigt von Besuchen beim Vater nach Hause komme.

What does *von etwas beunruhigt* mean in this context? Why 'Mia comes home dismissing and disturbed about her visiting her Dad.'?

Comment: Where is the problem? Without knowing English very good (but this isn't an English site, is it?) `... and disturbed from visiting her dad.`

Comment: Tschhuldigung. Ich habe vergessen, dass das ein deutsche Webseite ist.

Comment: @user3480 Auf Englisch zu fragen ist erlaubt. Andrerseits: Would you mind [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? eventually?

Comment: Even though _beunruhigt von etwas_ exists (_von_ giving the cause: _beunruhigt von dem seltsamen Geräusch_), here it does not belong together. Instead, _von_ relates to _nach Hause kommen_: return home from a visit.

Comment: We may speak both here, German, and English: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in

Comment: @c.p.: Ich kritisiere nicht, dass er auf Englisch fragt, sondern dass er nach einer geeigneten, engl. Übersetzung fragt; m.E. eine Frage für Englischexperten.

Comment: @userunknown das ist eher als Phrase mit "unbekannter" Bedeutung zu verstehen und daher (vorher) falsch getagged, in dem Fall wird das Englische zum einfacheren Verständnis verwendet. Außerdem ist der Ausgangspunkt ja der deutsche Satz, von demher viel besser hier als auf ELU & EL

Answer (score 6):

In your sentence "beunruhigt" is an adjective to Mia.  As you noted, it describes her as puzzled, troubled, worried, or discomposed.  The sentence does not specify how in particular the visits make her puzzled.  The sentence simply states that she sometimes returned in this state.

"Von etwas beunruhigt" means "troubled by something", but note that this phrase does not occur in your example! The "von" is the "from" in "return from visit".

Comment: By the way, if you think this is a correct answer, click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Als Grund gab die dreifache Mutter an, dass Mia manchmal so abweisend und beunruhigt von Besuchen beim Vater nach Hause komme.

I don't see a `von` in connection with `beunruhigt` here. There is only `nach Hause kommen von`

Here's what [leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=beunruhigt&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) says concerning the verb

**`beunruhigt  - concerned`**